Question on constructing the normal coordinate from direct computation.
I am reading Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry" 3rd Edition.
In exercise 2.5.20, he suggested using a general set of coordinates $y^i$ around $p$ with $y^i(p) =0$, set $x^i = \alpha^i_j(y)y^j$ and adjust $\alpha^i_{j} (0)$ , $ \frac{ \partial \alpha^i_j }{ \partial y^k} (0) $ to make $(x^1, \ldots , x^n)$ a normal coordinate.
I can understand how to adjust $\alpha^i_j(0) $ to get $g_{ij} = \delta^i_j$ where $g_{ij}$ is the (i,j)-component of the metric tensor g under the coordinate $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$. However, I don't know how to adjust $\frac{ \partial \alpha^i_j}{\partial y^k}(0)$ to get $\partial_k g_{ij} = 0$.
So far, I know two ways to construct the normal coordinate, one is using the exponential map and the other is by defining $ x^i = y^i - \frac{1}{2} \Gamma^i_{mn} y^m y^n$ which is presented in Aubin's book. I can verify those formulations satisfy the desirable condition but I have a hard time getting $ x^i = y^i - \frac{1}{2} \Gamma^i_{mn}y^my^n$ from the condition of normal coordinates. From the exponential map construction, the choice of $\alpha^i_j$ will never be unique...
I want to know how to adjust $\frac{\partial \alpha^i_j}{\partial y^k}(0)$ through the calculation of $\partial_k g_{ij}$.

What is the formula for $g_{ij}$? What are the first derivatives at $0$?
